# How to make the Ember Local Storage Adapter (LSAdapter) work with the Ember REST Adapter?

Tags: ember.js, local-storage

I would like to take advantage of both the Ember Local Storage Adapter (LSAdapter) and the Ember REST Adapter (RESTAdapter), so that there is a centralized database for all the users while avoiding sending an Ajax request for each user action.

Specifically, I would like to:

1. Populate the LSAdapter with data from the server.
2. All changes users make are updated to the LSAdapter. (I know how to do this step)
    (In preparation for #3, I can have a model that saves a log in LSAdapter of all the updates)
3. Once in n minutes, the LSAdapter update data are sent back to the server.

My backend server is NOT Rails, so please make the answers generic.

**Is it possible to use BOTH LSAdapter and RESTAdapter in an Ember app? If so, please provide code sample of how to set it up.**
I would also appreciate if you provide code sample for steps 1 and 3, basically, how a database can talk to the local storage and vice versa.

---

If it's not possible to have both LSADapter and RESTAdapter, what can I do to accomplish steps 1 and 3?

The only get around I can think of is to set up the Ember app store as a RESTAdapter, but then call [Web Storage localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) directly in my app, not calling it from LSAdapter at all.  Let me know if there is an easier or built-in way.

Answer (score 2):

After reading Ember data's DS.Store comments, it looks like it might be possible to use [2 adapters at once](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/83f9f6b9124612d3ac0b8ab34ad98b6028800138/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L67-L75):

1. You can retrieve models from the store in several ways. To retrieve a record
   for a specific id, use `DS.Model`'s `find()` method:

   `var person = App.Person.find(123);`
2. If your application has multiple `DS.Store` instances (an unusual case), you can
   specify which store should be used:

   `var person = store.find(App.Person, 123);`

I will update this answer if I try it out and get it working.

---

Update 1:

Check out the code in [UPDATED for Additional question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17540651/733034) where both *FixtureAdapter* and *RestAdapter* are called.

Answer (score 0):

```
//define your main adapter as usual

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 13,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
      url: app.apiUrl,
      namespace: app.apiNamespace
  })
});


//App.Product for example will use the rest adapter
App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
});


App.Somemodel = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
});

//App.Somemodel for example will use the fixture adapter
App.Store.registerAdapter('App.Somemodel', DS.FixtureAdapter);
```

Comment: as above question is applicable for my requirement as well. Still the question remains the same. The requirement is _Product_ model should act `RESTAdapter Model` while fetching data from the server and act `LocalStorageAdapter Model` while handling client side data management.