# What is the state of offline-syncing in ember at the moment?

Tags: cordova, ember.js, ember-data, epf

I need to build a phonegap/cordova app which keeps a local copy of models which can be amended and then be synced remotely to the server?

So far I've found:

- ember-data-sync: dead
- ember-data: doesn't support sync
- epf: looks
  like the best shot, but not hugely active and doesn't seem to have
  been updated past 1.0.0.rc6

What's the best way for me to achieve this, and what software stack, with versions do I need to use in order to do so?

Or would it be advisable for me to use a different js framework for me to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/kurko/ember-sync seems like the most active.

Discussions continue here: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-data-in-an-on-and-off-line-scenario/2639/31

There's suggestions that data-sync will make it into ember core at some point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the afterModel property of the router.

See :
[How to call an Ember data function directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538896/how-to-call-an-ember-data-function-directly)

This answear helped me and gave me the idea of switching from Local Adapter to Rest Adapter.

This snippet of code may also help you: http://jsbin.com/uduzin/3/edit

Once I will succeed, I will share my code.